# How to write on a picture without the picture being erased?

Tags: image-editing, pictures

I have this picture and I want to write something on it. How can I do that in a way that the picture stay there in the background without too much of it being errased.

[image]

Comment: Use a drawing tool, create a new layer, add text, export/save.. Photoshop, photopea, paint.net....  There are lots out there

Comment: Do you mean manually or programmatically?

Comment: @zx485 manually

Comment: You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

Comment: That's a very common feature on all kinds of image-related software.  You may even be able to do it in your word processor.  With actual image software, you can even do things like make the text semi-transparent, so not only doesn't it replace image outside of the "ink", you can still see the image through it.  For any kind of specific help, you would need to identify the software you want to use, and clarify what specific questions you have after trying to follow the application help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most image editors such as GIMP have toolboxes containing different editing tools arranged in a grid formation. The text tool usually has a capital letter for an icon. In the screenshot the Text Tool icon in GIMP is a capital **A**. In Paint.NET the Text Tool icon is a capital .

Select the text tool, click anywhere in the image, start typing some text, and the text will be superimposed over the image. When you select the text tool it also opens up a small settings pane that allows you to change the font, font size and color of the text.

[image: GIMP Text Tool]

After you have typed the text on the image, you can click the Move tool which looks like a four-way arrow to move the text into the position where you want it to be anchored to the image.